# MariaDB Select SUM wit Distinct in columns

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have one table "TABLE1" ...  in that table I have 2 columns InvoiceNumber and Total

when invoice is created that creates line like

InvoiceNumber     Total
1                            5.75
1                            5.75
1                            5.75
2                            3.25
2                            3.25
3                            9.99
3                            9.99
3                            9.99

And of course thers is lot of other column contains the line details... but the Total column is the total of the invoice...

I need to get the SUM of the column total but with DISTINC select on the invoicenumber column...

I wish my explanation is now better !!! :)

Tank you very much I appreciate it !

Old question ....

I Have this kind of query... but I dont know exactly how to write it to make it work...  Someone can help me ?   Tank you very much and sorry if my englis is not very good ...

```
SELECT
  SUM(1Z1.TotalStx) AS TotSTX,
  1Z1.Dept,
  1Z1.TrType,
  ItemDept.DeptNumber,
  ItemDept.VenteEncaisse
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT 1Z1.InvoiceNumber)
JOIN ItemDept ON ItemDept.DeptNumber = 1Z1.Dept
WHERE Dept <> '0'
  AND DateHre >= '2017-11-01'
  AND DateHre <= '2017-11-30 23:59:59'
  AND ItemDept.VenteEncaisse = '1'
ORDER BY 1Z1.Id;
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? What is 1Z1? A table? Explain what you want the query to do. Show sample data and expected results.

Comment: Are you showing us the _input_ data?  Or the _output_ data.  We need to see both.

Comment: I Found a other way to do what I need and it work very good...

I want to say tanks a lot to try helping me... !

Answer (score 0):

If you want the DISTINCT values of InvoiceNumber, then which Dept, TrType, etc are you hoping to get?

Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE 1Z1`.  If it shows `PRIMARY KEY(InvoiceNumber)`, then there is no ambiguity *and* `DISTINCT` is unnecessary.  If that is not the PK, then you need to figure out how to deal with the ambiguity before moving forward.

What table is `DateHre` in?

Comment: I modify my question and add more details...  tanks for your help